# Git Push to Teamcity CI

Tags: git, teamcity

(using .net, TeamCity, git)

To create a repository with git that our team can push to, it needs to be `--bare`. This works for source control.

However this `--bare` repository is the one that will be monitored to trigger CI builds using TeamCity. The question I have is how can I use this repository to trigger builds because there is no code (`.sln`) in a bare repository?

I have tried several configurations, but I can not create a remote repository that can be pushed to, and will trigger builds when it is.

Thanks for your help,

Paul

Comment: hi, i have solved this, i am writing a blog about it this weekend (www.comoke.com) where the answer will be.. ill post it in here as well to keep good form ...

Comment: I sill have posted here two possible approaches. Let me know if I were close ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update January 2012:

[Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6486/jon) mentions in the comments that [TeamCity version 6.5.6](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/whatsnew/) has great intergration for Git, which would render the hooks I suggests below not needed.

It includes for instance:

**Personal Builds on branches for Git and Mercurial**

> TeamCity 6.5 provides a more natural way to start Personal Builds on server with distributed version controls.

[image: personal build change]

---

Original answer November 2010

You can setup two repositories:

- one bare, where your team ushes to
- one non-bare

On the bare one, add a [post-update hook](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) which will:

- go to the non-bare repo
- make a pull

post-update hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /path/to/non-bare/repo &&
unset GIT_DIR
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

[This article](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) suggests another approach (non-bare repo with a `checkout -f` on a post-receive hook)

The general idea remains to update a non-bare repo, in order for your TeamCity instance to work on that set of files.

Comment: thanks VonC, perfect answer.. i went the two repositories bare / non bare with a post update hook on the bare one.. i cant vote it up becasue ive not got enough rep yet :o thanks again..

Comment: Version 6.5.6 has great intergration for GIT.  no need for hooks etc.  seemless with github out of the box

Comment: @Jon: good point. I have updated my answer to reflect that new state.